# MongoDB GridFS "illegal chunk format' exception

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I've been writing an app in Node.js that stores images in MongoDB's GridFS file system.

I've uploaded images through the app, and the images appear to be stored correctly:

```
$ mongofiles -v -d speaker-karaoke get howard-basement-100x115.jpg
Tue Jul 17 12:14:16 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1
Tue Jul 17 12:14:16 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Tue Jul 17 12:14:16 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1
done write to: howard-basement-100x115.jpg
```

This grabbed the .jpg out of MongoDB and I was able to open it no problem, so it looks like what I'm uploading is being stored correctly.

However, in my running application, when I attempt to read the same file, I get:

```
12:15:44 web.1     | started with pid 89621
12:15:45 web.1     | Connecting to mongodb://localhost/speaker-karaoke
12:15:45 web.1     | Speaker Karaoke express app started on 5000
12:15:48 web.1     | DEBUG: Get review thumbnail for 5005b7550333650000000001
12:15:48 web.1     | 
12:15:48 web.1     | node.js:201
12:15:48 web.1     |         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
12:15:48 web.1     |               ^
12:15:48 web.1     | Error: Illegal chunk format
12:15:48 web.1     |     at Error (unknown source)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at new <anonymous> (/Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/chunk.js:43:11)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at /Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js:488:24
12:15:48 web.1     |     at Cursor.nextObject (/Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:462:5)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:456:12)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at [object Object].g (events.js:156:14)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at [object Object].emit (events.js:88:20)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at Db._callHandler (/Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1290:25)
12:15:48 web.1     |     at /Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:329:30
12:15:48 web.1     |     at [object Object].parseBody (/Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:118:5)
12:15:48 web.1     | process terminated
12:15:48 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

Using this code (CoffeeScript, for Express):

```
  app.get "/images/review-thumbnail/:id", (req, res) ->

    id = req.params.id

    util.debug "Get review thumbnail for #{id}"

    store = new GridStore mongoose.connection.db, new ObjectID(id), null, "r"

    store.open (err, file) ->

      throw err if err

      util.debug "Store open for #{id}, type = #{file.contentType}"

      # TODO: Scale the image before sending it!

      res.header "Content-Type", file.contentType

      store.stream(true).pipe res
```

So it doesn't seem to be even making it to the callback passed to store.open().

Is there a problem opening a GridFS file when you know the id, but not the file name?

BTW:

```
$ npm ls
speaker-karaoki@0.0.1 /Users/hlship/workspaces/github/speaker-karaoke
├─┬ blueimp-file-upload-node@1.0.2  extraneous
│ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ ├── imagemagick@0.1.2 
│ └── node-static@0.6.0 
├── coffee-script@1.3.3 
├─┬ connect-assets@2.1.9 
│ ├── connect-file-cache@0.2.4 
│ ├── mime@1.2.2 
│ ├─┬ snockets@1.3.4 
│ │ ├── coffee-script@1.3.3 
│ │ ├── dep-graph@1.0.1 
│ │ └── uglify-js@1.0.7 
│ └── underscore@1.1.7 
├─┬ express@2.5.9 
│ ├─┬ connect@1.9.1 
│ │ └── formidable@1.0.11 
│ ├── mime@1.2.4 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ └── qs@0.4.2 
├─┬ jade@0.26.0 
│ ├── commander@0.5.2 
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
├─┬ mongodb@1.0.2 
│ └── bson@0.0.6 
├─┬ mongoose@2.7.0 
│ ├── hooks@0.2.1 
│ └─┬ mongodb@1.0.2 
│   └── bson@0.0.6 
├─┬ passport@0.1.10 
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
├─┬ passport-twitter@0.1.3 
│ ├─┬ passport-oauth@0.1.9 
│ │ ├── oauth@0.9.7 
│ │ └── passport@0.1.11 
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
├── sass@0.5.0 
└── underscore@1.3.3
```

And here's the function where it is failing:

```
var Chunk = exports.Chunk = function(file, mongoObject) {
  if(!(this instanceof Chunk)) return new Chunk(file, mongoObject);

  this.file = file;
  var self = this;
  var mongoObjectFinal = mongoObject == null ? {} : mongoObject;

  this.objectId = mongoObjectFinal._id == null ? new ObjectID() : mongoObjectFinal._id;
  this.chunkNumber = mongoObjectFinal.n == null ? 0 : mongoObjectFinal.n;
  this.data = new Binary();

  if(mongoObjectFinal.data == null) {
  } else if(typeof mongoObjectFinal.data == "string") {
    var buffer = new Buffer(mongoObjectFinal.data.length);
    buffer.write(mongoObjectFinal.data, 'binary', 0);
    this.data = new Binary(buffer);
  } else if(Array.isArray(mongoObjectFinal.data)) {
    var buffer = new Buffer(mongoObjectFinal.data.length);
    buffer.write(mongoObjectFinal.data.join(''), 'binary', 0);
    this.data = new Binary(buffer);
  } else if(mongoObjectFinal.data instanceof Binary || Object.prototype.toString.call(mongoObjectFinal.data) == "[object Binary]") {    
    this.data = mongoObjectFinal.data;
  } else if(Buffer.isBuffer(mongoObjectFinal.data)) {
  } else {
    throw Error("Illegal chunk format");
  }
  // Update position
  this.internalPosition = 0;
};
```

*Solution*

Updating the solution here as it does not render correctly in the comments below.

The problem was the duplication; having two copies, even with the same version, of mongodb and bson.

Fortunately, mongoose exports the mongodb it requires as property mongo, so I was able to remove the explicit mongodb from my `package.json` and changed:

```
mongo = require "mongodb"
mongoose = require "mongoose"
```

to:

```
mongoose = require "mongoose"
mongo = mongoose.mongo
```

Things are now looking nice; I still think the module system needs a sanctioned way to access a dependencies dependencies (for the case where a dep is not thoughtful enough to expose its deps).

Comment: Are you writing the GridFS file with node/mongo, or some other way?

Comment: I'm writing to GridFS using node/mongo; I can show that code if it helps, but the fact that the mongofiles command line tool can read the file contents correctly makes me think I'm doing it ok.

Comment: Yeah, just double checking. There's no real standard for GridFS so I was wondering if it were a driver inconsistency. Since you're writing with the Node driver, though, I don't think that's it.

Comment: Changed my code to generate a file name based on the ObjectID. The file name was used when the GridStore is created for both write and read. However, this didn't change the behavior, so the file name (or lack) is not the really issue.

Comment: Hm. Seems to be working now. I just went through some aggressive npm work; deleting node_modules and re-running npm install.

I know that I had two competing copies of the mongodb module and that may have caused an issue.  I want to research this further.

Comment: As noted below, it is back.  Using the debugger, I can see that mongoObjectFinal.data is type Binary, but fails the "instanceof Binary" check, and I don't know why.  I suspect there are two different version of Binary around.

Comment: thanks, i run into this issue after updating my app today, your solution is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I encountered this problem tonight, and your resolution cleared it right up for me.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it was duplicate copies (same version) of mongodb module;  removing node_modules and nmp install seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Darn it, its back. Just updated to mongoose@3.1.2 and mongodb@1.1.7.  There's two copies of mongodb, but they are both the same version.

Comment: And I can verify that mongofiles command can read the content correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I really solved it this time.  I am now pretty certain it was a conflict between two versions of the mongodb and bson modules.

Comment: See the *solution* note above (I had to move it there because formatting inside comments is too limited).