# Reading File from GridFS gives Illegal chunk format Error

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

*Code:*

```
var test_id = new ObjectID();    
var gridStore = new GridStore(mongoose.connection.db, test_id , 'test_gs_getc_file' , 'w');
    gridStore.open(function(err, gridStore){
        var data = fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg');
        gridStore.write(data, function(err, doc){
            gridStore.close(function(err, doc){
                GridStore.read(mongoose.connection.db, test_id , function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("ERROR", err);
                    }else{
                        console.log("FILE data", data);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

The file is getting saved in the `fs.chunks` and `fs.files` collections. 
But when i try to read the file it gives `Illegal chunk format` error.

I tried

1. writeFile method, but it leads to same error
2. [reinstalled mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529458/mongodb-gridfs-illegal-chunk-format-exception), but it leads to same error

*Complete Error message:*

```
C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mon
godb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:594
        throw err;
              ^
Error: Illegal chunk format
    at Error (unknown source)
    at new exports.Chunk (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_modules
\mongodb\lib\mongodb\gridfs\chunk.js:43:11)
    at nthChunk (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_modules\mongodb\
lib\mongodb\gridfs\gridstore.js:582:24)
    at Cursor.nextObject (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_modules
\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:680:5)
    at Cursor.nextObject.commandHandler (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\popula
te\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:658:14)
    at Db._executeQueryCommand (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_m
odules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1659:20)
    at g (events.js:192:14)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\rajsubramanian\nodeapps\populate\node_
modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:410:25)
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (C:\Users\rajsubrama
nian\nodeapps\populate\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\co
nnection\server.js:580:20)
DEBUG: Program node app exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: thanks @Derick for asking. I have updated the question with full error trace.